# Objective-C UITableView cell image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

So I have a **UITableView** of Facebook Friends and for a cell I want to add the image to it.

When I try the following code:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString: (@"http://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture")]]];
```

Everything works fine. Although that's hardcoding the image destination but when I do something like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString: (@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", thisFriend.friendID)]]];
```

It gives me a warning stating 'Expression result unused' whilst pointing at the @ symbol before the link.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I also tried:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:thisFriend.friendPhoto];
```

But that's giving me a 'Incompatible pointer types sending UIImage to parameter of type NSString' warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace: `(@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", thisFriend.friendID)` with this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", thisFriend.friendID];
```

Looks like you just forgot the method for formatting a string.

Comment: That did the trick. How embarrassing on my part! Thanks Bek :)

Comment: It's happened to all of us!

Comment: Here's another quick question: How can I make it something like this instead:
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage thisFriend.friendPhoto];

Comment: `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thisFriend.friendPhoto]`, but I think that you'll have to make sure that friendPhoto contains the full path of the image.

Comment: But thisFriend.friendPhoto is not a file. It's an UIImage. Meaning I just tested it, and it didn't work :P

Comment: Then just use assignment... cell.imageView.image = thisFriend.friendPhoto;  I think it would help you a lot to go through the Apple sample code for table views.

Comment: I honestly didn't think it was as simple as that. It never crossed my mind I mean. Anyway, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", thisFriend.friendID]]]];
```