# Setting the navigation title to 2 strings

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title says..I'm trying to make the navigation title to be the first and last name of a person.

```
self.title = @"%@ %@", [self.friend friendFirstName], [self.friend friendLastName];
```

It just comes up as:

```
%@ %@
```

What am I doing wrong? It's late, i'm tired..it could be some small mistake!

Comment: I just wonder because you made the **identical "small mistake"** in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594884/objective-c-uitableview-cell-image (and got and accepted the correct answer) ...

Comment: I have an absolutely terrible memory, and cannot seem to remember the smallest of things. Care to comment further?

Comment: Care to read the answer to your previous question??

Comment: Honestly I've forgotten that I've asked the question before. I do that sometimes. I can't stress how bad my memory is. Definite thanks for the reminder though. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a small mistake.

You forgot to use the `stringWithFormat:` method, like this:

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.friend friendFirstName], [self.friend friendLastName]];
```

Comment: Dear god. I'm definitely sleepy! Thanks :)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept it in order to remove your question from the Unanswered section =)

Comment: Of course. Waiting for the 10 minute timer to accept. :)